# Getting user birthday from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get user birthday from Facebook. I can get name, email, id but not birthday.

**Here is my code**

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button_fb);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
    callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    try {
                        String bday=graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("birthday");
                        Log.i("Bdayyyyy---",bday);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("Login Activity", graphResponse.toString());
                }

            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for permission for birthday as you can't get a user's birthday without an Extended **Profile** **Permission** of **user_birthday**.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Activity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_birthday"));
```

Comment: but where should i put this line?
I have used facebook sdk's butoon(Default one).

Comment: 02-17 02:59:45.637  15274-15274/app.com.maxell I/Login Activity﹕ {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"938874046189823","name":"Priyam Tayade","email":"priyam_tayade@yahoo.com","gender":"male"}, error: null}

Still getting this only.

Comment: google it you need to ask Extended Profile Permission of "user_birthday".